# How to convert hex literal like '\xc2' into ASCII with python?

Tags: python, hex, ascii

This is shockingly difficult to do, and I've been searching for the last half hour how to do this.  I've tried binascii, but haven't had any luck.

I want to convert '\xc2' into Â.  How can I do this with python?

Comment: Your attempts would be nice to see. Did you try `print u'\xc2'.encode('utf8')
`, for instance? (Probably not, since it says `Â`.)

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? If it's 3, then `'\xc2'` and `'Â'` are just different representations of the exact same string, so you don't need to do anything to convert one to the other. If it's Python 2, then you need to call `decode` on ``'\xc2'`` to get back `u'Â'`.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can't convert it to ASCII (or Shift-JIS or any other encoding that doesn't have the U+00C2 character), unless you're asking how to convert with `errors='replace'` so you get `b'?'` or something? You can encode it to Latin-1 (in which case you get `b'\xc2'`) or UTF-8 (`b'\xc3\x82'`) or UTF-16 (`b'\xff\xfe\xc2\x00`) or any other encoding that actually includes that character, of course.

Comment: For python 3 it's same symbols,  for those who will search, how to convert utf8 symbol with glyphs to ASCII, then you loose information and in simplest case you can use something like this 

    my_string=u'\xc2Â'
    >>>my_string
    'ÂÂ'
    my_string=my_string.replace(u'\xc2','A')
    >>>my_string
    'AA'

Also, you can try some libraries, like 
[https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/][1]
or [https://github.com/orsinium/homoglyphs][2]


  [1]: https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/
  [2]: https://github.com/orsinium/homoglyphs

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert it to ASCII because 'Â' is not part of the ASCII table. You need to decode it using the proper enconding. In this case, you should use `latin1`:

```py
foo = b'\xc2'
bar = foo.decode('latin1')
```

Comment: If the OP actually has `'\xc2'` (assuming this is Python 3), they can't `decode` it. And they don't _have_ to do decode it. `'\xc2'` is a Unicode string containing the character U+00C2, or `'Â'`.  In other words, they already have exactly what they're looking for, so there's nothing to call on it.